# Как добавить фоновое изображение под Android?

Tags: android, android-ui

Собственно проблема, есть файл png (сам файл размером 1920 на 1080). Я положил его в папку drawable. Прописал background в xml layout. На эмуляторе все прекрасно работает. На телефоне фон белый и картинки не видно. Пример разметки

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/image"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Недостаточно сведений, чтобы воспроизвести проблему. Как здесь [задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю какие тут еще детали можно написать. Я с удовольствием добавлю деталей, вы только скажите какие.

Comment: Покажите размтку и попробуйте уменьшить изображение

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждому приложению выделяется определённый объем памяти под картинки. В новых устройствах чуть больше, в старых поменьше. Поэтому вы должны понимать, что тестировать ваше приложение на реальном, желательно современном, устройстве, а не на эмуляторе. На моем тестовом устройстве Xperia M с 6 версией Android телефон воспринял [картинку](http://more-sky.com/data/out/9/IMG_339501.png) отлично.

В нормальных же случаях, картинка очень желательно должна находиться, например, в объекте `imageView`. Там же воспользоваться `android:scaleType="fitXY"` такой режим растягивает/сжимает картинку, чтобы подогнать её к контейнеру, или `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` для логотипов без фона. А как работать с imageView на фоне можно легко поискать в интернете, на этот случай рассмотренно  много способов.

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ms"/>
```

Но картинка не будет на весь экран, и нужно найти способ сделать её во весь.

Что же там у вас - нужно смотреть в исходники, телепаты в отпуске.

Например, добавив `android:background="@drawable/ms"`в `RelativeLayout` картинка на моем телефоне отобразилась без труда.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот сама картинка которую я пытаюсь запихнуть https://yadi.sk/i/nCVt0-xF3ET6XP

Comment: а просто background плохо использовать?

Comment: можно. я не так высказался, бэкграунд наносить действительно лучше чем в imageView, но в целом всё зависит от задачи. галвное чтобы работало. https://pp.vk.me/c637530/v637530232/2ed64/237OMN7Dj-s.jpg

Comment: У меня на Samsung S5 с Android 6 почему то не отображается....

Comment: попробуйте поиграться с разрешением и другими картинками с теми же параметрами. это всё что я и скорее всего остальные, смогут вам здесь посоветовать.

Comment: Спасибо! По крайне мере сам ход мысли я понял а это главное!